# Which oracle should I download for windows 7 x64?

Tags: oracle, windows

My os is: windows 7 x64

I tried to download oracle and install it in my computer, but I have downloaded 3 different oracle releases(including oracle 11G), they can't be installed.

They reported such error:

```
Need os version: 5.1, ..., 6.0
But found: 6.1
```

I have spent a day to download them, that I don't know which one I should try.

Is there any oracle 10G can run in windows 7 x64? If not, oracle 11G would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm re-reading your post, trying to determine if you're having problems installing 10g, 11g or both.  Whichever, I found an article on [how to install Oracle 11g on Windows 7](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/11/27/oracle-11g-on-windows-7/), describing the problem that you're having above.  Basically, the installer should present you with an option to override the prerequisite OS check.  Follow the link, go to step #3 and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Database 11gR2 (ie: 11.2.0.1 and above) is when support for Windows 7 x64 officially began. If you downloaded any of the 11gR2 releases it should install just fine (I've installed 11.2.0.1 on Win7 x64).

You can download the files from [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com) or here: [Oracle Database Software Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html).

Older versions (eg: 11gR1 11.1.0.7 and below) are not officially supported. Yes, you can disable the pre-requisite checks and install it. But do so at your peril.